# Paypal Button don't work PHP

Tags: php, html, paypal

I having a problem with my code every  time I click the paypal button it just post the information in my URL but do not redirect to paypal.

Here's my code. I can't post it since it is too long.

http://pastebin.com/aHPirpPr

Thanks in advance

Comment: At a quick glance, `if ($prd = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCheckPrd)) {` `if` should be `while`

Comment: I don't think sir that is the problem. but if I change it to while I dunno the next syntax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a second `<form>` on your page. Which has the Update button. I'm guessing you're submitting the empty form?

Make sure that your form looks like this:

```
<form action="toPayPal">
    /* fields here */
    <input type="button" value="Click me!" />
</form>
```

and not:

```
<form action="toPayPal">
    /* fields here */
</form>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Click me!" />
</form>
```

Because in the latter case you're submitting an empty form. You can't split up forms like this.

Comment: But sir how can I do it without affecting the update?

Because if I put the the last

$checkoutbtn inside the for each it will be duplicated. and also tried it I put the last $checkoutbtn before the update and it doesn't redirect me to paypal.